# Compile GCC/FFMPEG libs

Tags: compiling, gcc, ffmpeg

Could not compile cpp files and some video libs.
All libs are actually installed and stored at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
Worked hard to search all possible ways to solve it, but still nothing.
Strongly advise

.sh file

```
g++ -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-write-strings -L/home/supernova/Downloads/ffmpeg/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -I/home/supernova/ffmpeg/include/ -o bin/ScreenRecorder src/main.cpp src/ScreenRecorder.cpp -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswresample -lm -lva -lpthread -lvorbis -lvpx -lopus -lz -lpostproc -ldl -lfdk-aac -lmp3lame -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile -lx264 -ltheora -lx265 -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -ldl -lrt -lbz2 -lasound -lSDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_ttf -lfreetype -lass -llzma -lftgl -lperl -lcrypto -lxcb -lxcb-shm -lxcb-xfixes -lao -lxcb-shape -lfftw3 -lltdl
```

Errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lva 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbis x
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvpx x
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopus
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfdk-aac
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmp3lame
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbisenc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbisfile
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lx264
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltheora
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lx265
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltheoraenc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltheoradec
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDLmain
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_ttf
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lass
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lftgl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-xfixes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lao
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-shape
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
```

---

Update:
I updated some libraries as per Gabriel's advice.

Now, I need to install dev packages for below libs

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDLmain
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_ttf
```

These three actually have been reinstalled few times, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed the devel packages? The *-dev packages are usually all the files necessary to compile code against a given library. As an example, to compile libx264, you will also need libx264-dev. A couple of years ago I’ve made a script to compile ffmpeg and it was not easy. My advice is that you look for a previously written script (search github) to learn more about the process.

Comment: Gabriel, you are right! I just installed ibx264-dev and ibx265-dev, and there are no errors for these libs! Is there a simple way to compile rest?

Comment: Finally got to next step, all libraries are fine, it compiled and works! Now I need to integrate open cv

Comment: Tried a lot of variants still bad for open cv syntax. Added these lines to sh file                                                   -I /usr/include/opencv2 \
    -L /usr/lib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_imgproc